# Fetching Gmail UI element

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

This is not strict Gmail-API question, but is closely related to Gmail.
I have small extension for Gmail that allows users to zoom on incoming emails and list of emails. [video explanation on YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LUJ6N95-bk)

For that to work, I need to fetch that upper-left corner element and inject button in it, so that users can easily invoke popup with zoom controls.

[image]

Problem is, in new Gmail, that element is changing **Class Name** regularly (second time in the last month), and since I'm fetching it trough ClassName, extension gets broken (no button injected).

Is there any "safe" element, that won't change class in the next update, so that I can hook my logic onto it?

I was thinking to fetch **form element** (the main search on top), and then trough hierarchy and previous sibling get that left element...
but I'm not sure if that will work, maybe because of some customization or right-to-left languages DOM structure is not the same

Comment: I would find the `a[href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"]` element, then work upwards from it (if needed).

Comment: @wOxxOm thx, I guess this is a **safer** way to get it...

Comment: Not sure if this would matter but if you have multiple Gmail sessions open the `/0/` part of the url will change number so that selector won't always work.

Comment: @wOxxOm after testing it, I found that url is not unique to desired element. There is at least one more with it (in the left menu/sidebar, inbox)

Comment: I am there too, I am considering using SVG image fragments (they are in DOM too), or tooltip/aria text (but that would depend on language).